# how to call method in the other method in the same class

Tags: python, python-3.x

new to coding and not really familiar with object-oriental programming, i set two methods in one class and the above method isn't run, the rest of the varablie are all running though.so can anyone here can help me out with this question?

```py
def send_notification_via_pushbullet(self,title, body):
        """ Sending notification via pushbullet.
            Args:
                title (str) : title of text.
                body (str) : Body of text.
        """
        data_send = {"type": "note", "title": title, "body": body}

        resp = requests.post('https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/pushes', data=json.dumps(data_send),
                            headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + ACCESS_TOKEN, 
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
        self.resp=resp
        if resp.status_code != 200:
            raise Exception('Something wrong')
        else:
            print('complete sending')   

def getData(self): 
      sense = SenseHat()
      sensorTemp = sense.get_temperature_from_humidity()
      cpuTemp = self.get_cpu_temp()
      roomTemp = sensorTemp - ((cpuTemp-sensorTemp)/1.5)
      humid = sense.get_humidity()
      os.environ['TZ'] = 'Australia/Melbourne'
      time.tzset()
      nowTime = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
      if roomTemp is not None:
          if humid is not None:
              roomTemp = round(roomTemp, 1)
              humid = round(humid, 1)
              self.rT=roomTemp
              self.humid=humid

      nearbyDevices = bluetooth.discover_devices()
      for macAddress in nearbyDevices:
            print("Found device with mac-address: " + macAddress)
            if macAddress == self.a:
                with open('config.json') as myfile:
                    data=json.load(myfile)
                    tmin = data['min_temperature']
                    tmax = data['max_temperature']
                    hmin = data['min_humidity']
                    hmax = data['max_humidity']
                if (tmin<= roomTemp <= tmax and hmin <= humid <= hmax)!=1:
                    message1=(("Current time is " + str(nowTime) + " Temperature is " + str(roomTemp) +"Celsius " + "Humidity rate is"+ str(humid)+"percent"))
                    message2=("Either temperature or humidity rate is Out of range")
                    self.send_notification_via_pushbullet(message1, message2)
                else:
                    message3=(("Current time is " + str(nowTime) + " Temperature is " + str(roomTemp) +"Celsius " + "Humidity rate is"+ str(humid)+"percent"))
                    message4=("Both temperature and humidity rate is within the range")
                    self.send_notification_via_pushbullet(message3, message4)
```

Comment: so the  self.send_notification_via_pushbullet(a,b) is not being called

Comment: Is any device found? What is `self.a`? There are lots of things that could prevent this method from getting called, we just can't know with the information you provided.

Comment: Then for none of `nearbyDevices` the condition is true or the iterable is empty.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille, the find- device method is called and no error is thrown,i have tested it already, so the device can be found and condition met. and i think the major problem is self.send_notification_via_pushbullet is a method name , we cant call the method name right ?

Comment: The way you call the method is right. So, your code never reaches the point where it would be called, which means that no device is found, or that the condition related to `self.a` is never satisfied, which probably wouldn't raise an exception.

Comment: ok i will go and test again to see any further problem